# ImportError: No module named 'libs.utils'

Tags: python

Using: `python 3.5.2, tensorflow gpu 0.12.0`

I am trying to run code for Autoencoders from [here](https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/blob/master/python/08_denoising_autoencoder.py). In the code snippet it asked to import a library which has a function `corrupt(x)`. To use this I am trying to import `from libs.utils import corrupt` but then I get error `ImportError: No module named 'libs.utils'`

How can I resolve this in Windows?

In the folder `C:\Users\raady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\libs` 
I have 4 files: `_tkinter.lib, libpython35.a, python3.lib, python35.lib`.

In the folder `C:\Users\raady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib` I don't have any folder libs.

To import this library to workspace, what should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/tree/master/python). It's the Github repo from where you found the example. You need to download the whole directory or at least the [libs](https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/tree/master/python/libs) directory in order to access the libs.utils module.

If you download the libs directory separately make sure you put it in the same directory as your example Tensorflow script.